# Is it better to create multiple schedulers in a single actor or multiple actors

Tags: scala, akka

I want to run certain tasks on a scheduled basis.
Some of then are every 15 minutes, while others are every 1 hour or daily.

Should I create multiple schedulers in a single actor or is it better to create multiple actors for this?

Comment: In the simplest version you would just use `system.scheduler.schedule` to create the scheduled actions. This is actually independent from actors. It can either send messages to an actor or execute any kind of code. It uses the internal scheduler which is based on a "HashedWheeledTimer". The default settings for this timer are probably not suited for long-running timers (also depending on the total number of timers) as a bucket will be linearly scanned for due timers in each tick.

Comment: Also see the documentation for `akka.scheduler.ticks-per-wheel` at https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/ad3ef5982/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L652. If that data structure doesn't fit your needs, you could build your own kind of timer e.g. using actors. For your kind of application it might be enough to have a single actor which schedules a tick every few seconds or even minutes and then  maintain a sorted list of tasks to execute.